# Maya 2013 error: Mayatomr.Geometry : unnamed object is not a mesh, ignored

Tags: compiler-errors, render, maya, autodesk

I want to render and merge groundplane with object
I use Maya 2013
when I try to execute it give me error:

```
convertLightmapSetup  -camera camera1 -showcpv;
// Baking 1 maps
// Cmd: convertLightmap  -camera camera1 initialShadingGroup 
           |ground_plane|ground_planeShape
// Warning: (Mayatomr.Lightmap) : Some objects do not have a bakeset assigned, 
                internal default settings are used for these objects. // 
// Warning: (Mayatomr.Shader) : initialShadingGroup-ground_plane:lm: 
 referenced writable texture file 



"C:/Users/.../Documents/maya/projects/default/renderData/mentalray/lightMap/
   baked-initialShadingGroup-ground_plane.tif" already exists, overwrite 
 **Error: (Mayatomr.Geometry) : unnamed object is not a mesh, ignored**
    // Baked 1 maps. 0 maps failed
    C:/Users/.../Documents/maya/projects/default/renderData/mentalray/lightMap/
     baked-initialShadingGroup-ground_plane.tif //
```

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Error suggests your groundplane object is not renderable geometry. Is it polygons? Nurbs?

Comment: I dont think this information alone is enough to solve the problem. Try not to bake initial shading group. Copy the shader first to different shading group (initialShadingGroup is a bit problematic in mr).

Answer (score 0):

Your Maya Scene have unwanted nodes, Select all objects and then "export selected" then open your file as new scene.

After that you will not see this error again. :)
 **Error: (Mayatomr.Geometry) : unnamed object is not a mesh, ignored**